# What's the current best practice for creating child objects on creation of the parent in Rails ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, initialization

I would like to create a child object any time an instance of the parent is created.

Thus calling Parent.new() will automatically generate a child object which is associated with the parent. I override the initializer (as below) but is there a better way? I need to pass in one of the parameters to the child object but I don't want to use nested attributes. It's for an API and the split should be invisible for the API users.

```
has_one :child
validates_associated :child

def initializer(args*)
   @child = Child.new(args[:some_argument])
   super
end
```

Comment: Given that this question was open ended, there isn't necessarily a single right answer. I'm therefore marking the one I found most useful as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's why ActiveRecord has callbacks like: `after_create` and `after_save`.

For what it's worth I know a famous open source project named **Spree** which has product and master variant(a child model: Variant) as dependency for a `Product` object.

Here's the code: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb#L236-L250

and: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb#L87

You can have an `after_create` to save the child object data.

And, in my opinion. You shouldn't be overriding initialize for models. You may end up running into circular dependency issues or some random bug later. Just saying..

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be using `after_initialize` callback:

`after_initialize -> { child = Child.new(child_attributes) }`

This would mean you'd have to also set attr_accessor for a parent object:

```
class Parent
  attr_accessor :child_attributes
end
```

This is just a different approach and it doesn't really look better to me. I don't think rails has anything OFTB for this case besides of `nested_attributes`